# Android work in background

Tags: java, android

I got 3 activities ( `A` , `B` ,`C` ) and a service that I call to check if I got new messages from DB. It's a HTTP request . I need to make the request each 15 sec.

```
 Thread t = new Thread() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    while (!isInterrupted()) {
                        Thread.sleep(15000);
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                // Here i call                               
                            }
                        });
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }
            }
        };

        t.start();
```

How to make it work when i am changing activities ?

Comment: I guess you are looking for services. Here is a guide to create one: http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/run-background-service/create-service.html

Comment: You have 3 choices to make it work at background independently: `Service`, `IntentService` and `AlarmManager`

Answer (score 0):

Option: Consider changing setup to have three fragments as your original activities, and a MainActivity that controls the repeat polling for messages to DB, as well as controlling the fragments.

Answer (score 0):

```
@SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
public class AlarmService extends Service {

    private PendingIntent pendingIntent;
    Handler mHandler;
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
    }

    public void f() {
        Toast t = Toast.makeText(this, "Service is still running",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        t.show();
  };
}
    @Override
    @Deprecated
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        Toast t = Toast.makeText(this, "Service started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        t.show();

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onStart(intent, startId);

        mHandler = new Handler();
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                f();
                mHandler.postDelayed(this, 20000);
            }
        };
        mHandler.postDelayed(r, 20000);

    }

}
```

and in manifest use this

```
<service android:name="com.example.yourservice"></service>
```